# Excel Graphs - Compound Type --> Double. Fill in the Gaps with Selected Colours

Tags: excel, graph

I have created a graph and changed the "Compound Type" to "Double".  It produces the following graph lines:

[image]

However, I wish to fill in the white space with my own selected colours.  I have checked online to no avail.  I have also tried creating it manually with 3 different lines for each section but looks awful!

Any help or ideas greatly appreciated.

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: can you please specify which 'white space' you were referring to? if you can provide another picture with the desired outcome that will be better.

Comment: Speculation: the "segments" in a line graph chart seem to be implemented through a "line" object (Like how you do Insert>Shapes>Line). However, in a **Sheet** when you do this type of line and then change the Compound type to Double, the Fill colour option is greyed out. I m guessing it's a bug that the fill colour in the **Chart** seems settable, but actually isn't, as that property seems nonexistant. IF this is true, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Hello Terry, sadly I am unable to provide another picture of desired outcome as I cant achieve this outcome.  In short the white space between the two red lines and the white space between the two dark blue lines.  So it is almost a solid line but the insides of the lines have a different shade.

Stax, I fear you may be right.